# How to check permission for userLocation

Tags: ios, ios6, user-permissions, userlocation

Is there a way to check if the user gave permission or not to my App use his/her location coordinates?
I'd like check this before he/she press a button to submit some info, and I'll only activate this button if user gave permission.

My app uses iOS 6.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your delegate of the `CLLocationManager` instance, implement the

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
```

method. If this method is called with its `error` parameter set to `kCLErrorDenied`, then the user has not enabled using the location services. You can also implement the

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status
```

method - when the `status` parameter of this callback method is not `kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied`, then the user has enabled your app to use his location.

[Documentation here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html)

Answer (score 1):

I created a component for ease of use permissions on iOS.

Available in my Github:

- https://github.com/douglasddf/iOS-Check-Permission

[image]

An example of use using block:

```
/*
   User can be choose two enum type for request the location authorization:
     - AuthorizeRequestTypeAlwaysAuthorization
     - AuthorizeRequestTypeWhenInUseAuthorization
     */

    [[IOSCheckPermissions globalInstance] checkPermissionAccessForLocation:self.locationManager
                                                      authorizeRequestType:AuthorizeRequestTypeWhenInUseAuthorization
      successBlock:^{

          // SUCCESS ...

    } failureBlock:^{
        // PERMISSION DENIED ...
    }];
```